# How to allow linebreaks between double surnames of an authoryear-style citation call-out

Tags: margins, citing, natbib

When citing with double surnames in 'Harvard style'  with the `natbib` package, it sometimes happens to have the start of the citation at the end of one line. It seems that `natbib` doesn't allow line-brakes inside a double surnames (even when there is a space between the names).

So the question arises, how is it possible to avoid this problem? An example, of the practical consequence of this behavior can be seen below:

[image]

I'm new to LaTeX, use a complex thesis template, and don't know how to reduce the margins, in order to reproduce the situation in the screenshot before. Therefore the minimal example code requires further alignment settings. Would be very thankful if you consider a try to solve the problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear, comma]{natbib} %
\usepackage{verbatim,filecontents} %

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

    @article{mochales2009,
        author = {Mochales Palau, Raquel and Ieven, Aagje},
        title = {Funny Article About the Name of the Elephant},
        journal = {Elephant Intelligence and Human Reactions},
        year = {2009},
        numpages = {22},
        publisher = {Serious Publisher},
        address = {Western Pacific, Easter Islands},
    }

\end{filecontents*}

\setlength{\textwidth}{9.5cm}
\begin{document}

Other argumentation based issues are ambiguity of theory, ambiguity of
argumentation itself and subjectivity of the interpretation of written
arguments \citep[p. 21]{mochales2009}. They used the structured part of
the Araucaria corpus.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thank you :) I'm sorry, couldn't reproduce the problem because I don't know how to reduce the margins properly. Please reed the explanation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly kludgy, but it works [!]: Insert an `\allowbreak` directive after the first part of the surname, i.e., write the `author` field as

```
author = {Mochales\allowbreak Palau, Raquel and Ieven, Aagje},
```

The output of the full MWE is as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear, comma]{natbib} 
\usepackage{verbatim,filecontents} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % just for this example

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{mochales2009,
        author = {Mochales\allowbreak Palau, Raquel and Ieven, Aagje},
        title = {Funny Article About the Name of the Elephant},
        journal = {Elephant Intelligence and Human Reactions},
        year = {2009},
        numpages = {22},
        publisher = {Serious Publisher},
        address = {Western Pacific, Easter Islands},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\setlength{\textwidth}{9.5cm}
\begin{document}

Other argumentation based issues are ambiguity of theory, ambiguity of
argumentation itself and subjectivity of the interpretation of written
arguments \citep[p.~21]{mochales2009}. They used the structured part of
the Araucaria corpus.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```